# how to add a comment in "tinymce" for user to see it and then add content in text area accordingly

Tags: tinymce

Right now i am adding a button in toolbar and disabling its border so that it seems as a comment to the user inserting content in tinyMCE textarea. Coded as:

```
theEditor.addButton('comment', {
        type: 'button',
        setDisabled :true,
        border: 'none',
        text: '  Please fill orderNo & alignment for every Content part you insert........', 
        onclick: function() {
        },
        icon: false,
        });
```

Please suggest if there are any other best methods to add a small instruction to textarea so that user follow that instruction while he is using textarea

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the standard way to accomplish that purely in the TinyMCE init.

You could definitely do it cleaner by replacing the button element with some actual styled labeling, if you wanted.